# Strange background-image bug on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My goal is to create a little slideshow, and I already made it here : https://jsfiddle.net/cas1g2ch/2/

Here's the code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="first-block">
    <div id="background-header">
        <div class="bg-wrapper">
            <div class="background-img-1"></div>
        </div><!--
        --><div class="bg-wrapper">
            <div class="background-img-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first-block{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}




@keyframes zoomPicture {
    0%{
        transform: scale(1.0); 
    }

    50%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    100%{
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

#background-header{
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    width: 200vw;
    height: 100vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #333;
}

#background-header > .bg-wrapper
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#background-header > .bg-wrapper > div{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    background-size: cover;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-name: zoomPicture;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#background-header  .background-img-1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.hd-wallpaper.images-fonds.com/modules/mg3/albums/Paysages_(landscapes)_Wallpaper_HD/Paysages/Paysage_(landscape)_wallpaper_HD_0025.jpg");
}

#background-header  .background-img-2 {
    background-image: url("http://unreveunvoyage.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/parc-national-de-banff-paysage-canada.jpg");
}
```

- Right now the slideshow has two pictures, and each picture covers the entire screen size (`width : 100vw ; height : 100vh ; background-size : cover`).
- To display the pictures I used `background-image`, and the backgrounds are fixed.
- Because I cannot animate a background with `background-size : cover`, I used `transform : scale` to add a little zoom effect.

The problems :

- On Chrome there's a weird Glitch (Chrome 56 on Windows), just use the scrollbar
  in the demo to see the problem,  here's a video I made that shows the
  problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHCLBTpxCAs (In this video I chose a high `transform: scale` value to better recognize the bug)
- On Firefox the backgrounds are not fixed, but the pictures are
  displayed correctly
- Surprisingly it works great on Internet Explorer 11
- It also seems to work on mobile

How can I fix this? What is the best workaround?

Comment: Just to let you know. On Chrome 56 Mac OS, I don't have the glitch. I have some flickering, but not your issue.

Comment: @Zetura Thanks for you feedback ! I haven't resolved the issue yet, so I  changed the animation properties.